# Open sets and closed sets

Tags: real-analysis

If say any set $A = \{x \in \mathbb Q \mid 2<x<8 \}$.

($\mathbb Q$ = set of rational numbers, $\mathbb R$ = set of real numbers )
(a) $A$ is open in $\mathbb Q$.
(b) $A$ is open in $\mathbb R$. 
Which one is correct?

My answer:- i know that option (a) is correct as every element in A is an interior point. But I couldn't convince myself that option (b) is incorrect.

Comment: See ["Open" is defined relative to a particular topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set#%22Open%22_is_defined_relative_to_a_particular_topology).

Answer (score 3):

The set $A$ is not open is $\mathbb R$, since $5\in A$, but NO open interval with 5 its center (i.e. open ball with center 5) is a subset of $A$, and this is because every open interval is $\mathbb R$ contains irrational numbers.